# Segmentation Fault in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've been trying to program a calculator and have come across an error I cannot fix. I get segmentation fault once I enter the calculation to be done. I thought a segmentation fault was when it ran out of memory so I tried removing both my loops, assuming they were the issue, but with no luck.

Could it be my mallocs?

```
int calculator()
{
int exit = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
exit = 1;
while(exit == 1){

    printf("Welcome to the calculator, please enter the calculation you wish to make, if you wish to exit type EXIT\n");

    float *num1 = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
    float *num2 = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
    char operation = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    float *ans = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
    char *string = (char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));

    scanf("%s", &string);
    int result = strncmp(string, "EXIT", 10);

    if(result == 0){
        exit = 0;
    }
    else{
        //scanf("%f%c%f", &num1, &operation, &num2);
        int length = strlen(string);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i <= length; i++){
            printf("forever");
            if(isdigit(string[i]) != 0){
                num1 = string[i];
            }
            else{
                operation = string[i];
            }
        }
        printf("num1%f\n", num1);
        printf("operation%c\n", operation);
        printf("num2%f\n", num2);

        if(operation == '+'){
            *ans = *num1 + *num2;
        }
        if(operation == '-'){
            *ans = *num1 - *num2;
        }
        if(operation == '/'){
            *ans = *num1 / *num2;
        }
        if(operation == '*'){
            *ans = *num1 * *num2;
        }
        if(operation == '^'){
            *ans = (float)pow(*num1,*num2);
        }

        printf("Your answer is %f\n", ans);

        }
}
return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

Welcome to the calculator, please enter the calculation you wish to make, if you wish to exit type EXIT
5+9
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Process returned 139(0x8B) execution time: 2.611s

The reason I used malloc was because the values I assigned to the variables were lost when I exited the for loop. Though this has not solved the issue, I feel there is something fundamentally wrong with my code.

Comment: Consider `scanf("%s", string);` for starters. And as Kyle has pointed out, your `operation` allocation is neither needed nor advised (as is most of this). `char operation;` is not a pointer type, and thus no need to allocation. its a pure stack-var. I suggest a good tutorial on pointers and formatted input procedures.

Comment: can you give us a sample output?

Comment: Using GDB or Valgrind is very helpful here.

Comment: If you use GCC, you can compile with -g and then use valgrind to see the exact line that failed. Chances are it's the `scanf("%s", &string);` one, seeing how `string` is already a pointer.

Comment: You don't cast `void *` in C....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char operation = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

should be

```
char operation; // you don't need to call malloc for a single byte
```

And:

```
int exit = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
int exit;
```

In fact, most for the data in your program is allocated with `malloc`, but it doesn't need to be. The reason these are causing problems with your code is because you are assign a pointer to non-pointer variables.

Also:

```
scanf("%s", &string);
```

should be

```
scanf("%s", string); // string is already declared as a pointer
```

This can easily cause a segmentation fault because you are storing the user-entered data at the address of the pointer, not the allocated space that the pointer points to.

Same goes here:

```
printf("Your answer is %f\n", ans);
```

should be:

```
printf("Your answer is %f\n", *ans);
```

And here:

```
printf("num1%f\n", num1);
// should be 
printf("num1%f\n", *num1);
```

And here:

```
printf("num2%f\n", num2);
// should be 
printf("num2%f\n", *num2);
```

And what's going on here?

```
num1 = string[i];
```

This is not going to work. When you cast a character to a `float` pointer, it's going to print out garbage.

Most of the problems with this code is due to invalid use of pointers. I would suggest, at least when you fix the fault, that you change all your pointers to compile-time data. You are also not freeing the data at the end of your program. This causes memory leaks - another reason to do away with your calls to `malloc`.

Maybe just try to avoid the use of pointers all together, for the time being.

Also:

*I thought a segmentation fault was when it ran out of memory*

Not really. Segmentation faults occur when you try to read/write an invalid place in memory. It may be due to a null pointer returned my malloc (may be due to low memory) but could also be a number of more likely reasons.

**Edit:**

Here's a non-pointer example of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

    char input[50];

    char operation = 0;
    float   num1 = 0.0f,
            num2 = 0.0f,
            ans  = 0.0f;

    printf ("Enter the calculation\n");

    scanf ("%f %c %f", &num1, &operation, &num2);

    if (operation == '+') printf ("The answer is %f\n", num1 + num2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. It looks like I've completely misunderstood using malloc. I am removing my mallocs

Comment: it happens, I added an example to go by. This *calculator* program is very common in begginning `C` classes and they often don't involve calls to `malloc`

Comment: I wanted for the user to be able to enter the whole string and then I wanted to split it into the operation and the numbers myself. This has proved difficult so I may have to go back to this way. Thanks

Comment: You can do that pretty easily with `scanf`. I updated my example

Comment: I originally started with that, wanted to incorporate the exit bit which has been far more hassle than it's worth. Is there any way I can have both? I really appreciate this help, thank you.

Comment: yeah. You could `scanf` into a string first. parse for "EXIT" using `strstr`. if it is found, exit the program. If it is not, use `sscanf` to find the calculation arguments.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably theses lines

```
int exit = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
exit = 1;
```

If you are allocating a (int *) then you don't assign it to an (int) because that's not the same type.

You probably want

```
int exit = 1;
```

or if you really want to use a pointer

```
int* exit = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*exit = 1;

while (*exit == 0) {
```

by assigning

```
int exit = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

you effectively take the address returned by the malloc and then cast it into an integer.  Which you then permanently lose the address by reassigning exit to 1 in the next line.  Since the address is now lost forever, you have a bit of memory that is allocated to your program, but no longer reachable from the program's code.  Such a thing is called a memory leak, and should be avoided.

That means every time you do a malloc, it is generally a very good idea to have it paired up with a free, like so:

```
/* near the beginning */
int* exit = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

... code ...

/* just after exit isn't used anymore */
free(exit);
```

Comment: similar issues exist with float*.  Odds are you really want float.  If this was done to avoid the compiler warnings about scanf, you changed the wrong spot.  Really you should have changed scanf to take the address of the variable, like &exit (instead of changing the type of the variable).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues:

```
int exit = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
exit = 1;
```

How you are storing a pointer in integer??

change it

```
int exit = 1;
```

Not again..!!

```
char operation = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Change it

```
char* operation = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

String is a pointer, don't send pointer to a pointer to scanf().

```
scanf("%s", &string);
```

change it

```
scanf("%s", string);
```

my goodness, i don't think you want to print the address of ans:

```
printf("Your answer is %f\n", ans);
```

change it

```
printf("Your answer is %f\n", *ans);
```

I'll not talk about the weird logic of your code. First fix the deadly issues.